# dynamic link button click event not firing

Tags: asp.net

my problem is that i am creating dynamic link buttons in a dynamically created cell.its working fine but the click event handler of dynamic link button  is not firing.i have searched enough on internet but nothing is working out..im calling 3 methods on page load.and the last method itself is calling the method which creates my dynamic link buttons..but still the click event is not firing...even oninit wont work because structure of my project is such.is there any other solution for this.

**EDIT**

```
       protected void viewFullLessonPlan()
       {
         for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            Label lbl;
            LinkButton lnk;
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                TableCell tCellLessonPlan = new TableCell();
                lbl = new Label();


                lnk = new LinkButton();



                   lbl.Text = dsperiodOfSub.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SubjectName"].ToString();
                    tCellLessonPlan = createCell(tCellLessonPlan.Text, "Periods");
                    tCellLessonPlan.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    lnk.Text = "Details";
                    lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.LinkButton_Click);

                    tCellLessonPlan.Controls.Add(lnk);
                }

                tRow.Cells.Add(tCellLessonPlan);

            }
            tbllesson.Rows.Add(tRow);
        }



    protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
        //some logic here
    }
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question without any code.

Comment: this code wont compile. It is having error at  tRow.Cells.Add(tCellLessonPlan); How can you declare a variable inside for loop and use it outside for loop?????

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
```

Your event handler will look like-

```
void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: i have already done that see my code above.its just that ur using         lnk.Click +=new EvenHandler(lnk_Click). & im using lnk.Click +=new System.EvenHandler(lnk_Click)...

Comment: its showing an error because while posting the code i have deleted sql queries and also i have not given the code for create cell.as its not important..important is just the creation of dynamic link buttons in dynamic cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an ID to your Link:

```
    lnk.ID = "lnk-" + j + "-" + i;
```

Also make sure that you are not creating the links in !Page.IsPostBack